# How to create a generic insert function for a custom container with a functor

Tags: c++, c++03

At this point, i'm not worried about this being the correct solution for my problem (in fact, it isn't) but i got into this problem and i couldn't solve it so it's been haunting me and i can't let go.

I have a generic container for POD types. This container can avoid copies by not initializing memory and not calling any constructor or destructors for performance reasons, in exchange of making the user responsible of this(which is not that big of a problem being pods and our use case).

This is a very simple demonstration on how to use this.

```
template <typename Pod_Type>
class PodContainer
{
public:
   //stl-like iterators for compatibility with stl-algorithms
   Pod_Type* begin();
   Pod_Type* end();
   //special "insertion" function that inserts a non-initialized pod
   Pod_Type* new_empty();

   //This "something" is my problem. I guess this has to be a functor. 
   //More on this later
   Something generic_insert;

private:
    Pod_Type* mStorage; //Allocated space for pods
};

//Simple structure to use as example
struct PodA
{
   int x,y,z;
};

//Function to initialize a pod of type podA with the given params
inline
init_podA( podA* ptr, int a, int b, int c) 
{
   ptr->x = a; ptr->y = b; ptr->z = c;
}


int main()
{
  //Create a buffer
  PodContainer<podA> buff;

  //Insert some elements and intialize them "by hand"
  for (int i=0; i < 10 ; ++i)
  {
     init_podA( buff.new_empty(), 1,2,3);
  }
}
```

Note that all the memory management issues for the container class are solved (i have already tested it extensively) and the container itself is a great fit for my real problem.

Now for the fun part. I want to make this "something" call my init_podA function from **inside** the container. Obviously i can't hardwire this inside the Buffer class because i don't even know how much parameters will need the next init_xxx function a user will need for his pod type. I started toying with the idea of passing a second parameter template to the PodContainer class, where the second is a traits class that i can query for the functor that wraps the call to the real initializing function. In the PodContainer class i could query the traits class and save the functor that will be constructed there that will be called by users and give the impression of being a member function.

The idea was that i would use this traits like this:

```
template<typename PodType, typename PodTraits = MyPodTraits<PodType> >
class PodContainer
{
 PodContainer():
      generic_insert(PodTraits::get_inserter(this))
 //The rest of the PodContainer definition
 ....    

//And the user of the container would see this
PodContainer<PodA> buffer;
buffer.generic_insert(a,b,c); //Calls buffer->new_empty and initializes a pod
```

Is this even possible? I guess i would be using some boost::bind trickery, am i right? What is the type of the functor so i can receive it in the container? Is there a better option??

Thanks!!

Edit: Note that i can't use c++11 :(

Comment: I think there might be some confusion here. First off, what is the point of a init function like `init_podA`? You do realize that the compiler essentially generates the exact same thing if you were to just give `podA` a constructor, yes?

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like STL's `emplace_back()` function?

Comment: Pretty much. I already saw stuff like that (from [folly's FBVector](https://github.com/facebook/folly/) ), but i can't use c++11 for the time being :(. Probably should add the restriction to the question.

Comment: @slavik262 This comes from escaping the STL design and avoiding copy constructors when working with batches of those pods. In any case, believe me, that's not the central point of the question,  this is mostly curiosity on how to do the other part.

Comment: What are you trying to do which is not possible with standard containers (there are many, choose one!)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can't use C++11 (and variadic templates), you can always go the hard way and provide an overload for every possible number of parameters. Like so:

```
void generic_insert(void (*init)(PodType*)) { init(new_empty()); }

template<typename A1>
void generic_insert(void (*init)(PodType*, A1), A1 a1) { init(new_empty(), a1); }

/* and so on ... */
```